# Modal textarea doesn't load data attribute from button it was clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/q387b96x/5/

1. Click button to open modal
2. Enter text
3. Click save
4. Click any other button, the same value you entered previously will show.

I want the modal to show the "data-text" attribute for the particular row it clicked on. I guess I need to update that attribute when saving also?

I assume the reason is that the text is not loaded into the modal correctly. I assume this is the offending code:

```
$('#commentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
         var text = $(e.relatedTarget).data('text');
         $('#textareaID').text(text);
         $('#btnSave').click( function () {
             //code to update in DB here
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because Bootstrap re-uses the same modal HTML. To fix your issue you can simply clear the `textarea` value when the modal is hidden.

Also note that need to use `val()` to set the value in a `textarea` element, not `text()`, and the `#Save` click handler would be better as a delegated event. Try this:

```
$('#commentModal').on({
  'shown.bs.modal': function(e) {
    var text = $(e.relatedTarget).data('text');
    $(this).find('#textareaID').val(text);
  },
  'hide.bs.modal': function(e) {
    $('#textareaID').val('');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function() {
    console.log('TODO: Implement save logic...')
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gpu25r4f/7/)

Comment: Thanks! A stupid question though: after moving the save event as a delegate - how can I access a data attribute from the button that was clicked to show the modal? in the shown.bs.modal function I can use var rowID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('rowID') - but that doesn't work in the btnSave click event.

Comment: Glad to help. Change `e.relatedTarget` to `this`.

Comment: Hmm... still can't get it to work. Neither the data attribute, or the current text in the textarea:
   $(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function() {

        var id = $(this).data('timelisteid');

        var text =  $('#textareaID').val();

id shows up as "undefined" and text shows up empty.

Comment: I just checked the fiddle and the save button doesn't seem to have either of those data attributes?